# Retrieving one set of values from Generic class with different types

Tags: java, generics

I have a generic class with multiple parameter type.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Label<Type1,Type2> {
private Type1 key;
private Type2 value;

public Label(Type1 obj1, Type2 obj2) {
    this.key = obj1;
    this.value = obj2;
}
}
public class practise {
    private ArrayList<Label<String,Integer>> mytest= new ArrayList<Label<String,Integer>>();
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        practise p = new practise();

        p.mytest.add(new Label<String,Integer>("Apple",10));
        p.mytest.add(new Label<String,Integer>("Orange",20));
        p.mytest.add(new Label<String,Integer>("Kiwi",30));
        p.mytest.add(new Label<String,Integer>("Fig",10));
        
        for (Label<String,Integer> val:p.mytest) {
            System.out.println(val.getKey()+":"+val.getValue());
            
        }
        
    }
}
```

I know we can get the key values using the function getKey(). From the above class is it possible to fetch only the String keys as an array from myTest, like getAllKeys() function. **I know we can loop through and fetch them** just curious if there are any available functions already. Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please make sure that your code actually compiles before posting a question here -- I'm pretty sure that you'll be getting a compiler error because neither `getKey ()` nor `getValue ()` are defined. Please [edit] your question accordingly to include compileable code! This hint could also lead you to the answer to your actual question.

Comment: @AlexanderLeithner actually the above code compiles well and works.The getKey() or getValue methods are default from Generics class.

Comment: No, it does not. Try to put this code into a file and run `javac` over this file -- it'll throw the error that `getKey()` and `getValue()` are not defined (which, in fact, is correct). `Label<>` is not `extend`ing any base class other than `Object` and there is no such thing as a "Generics class" you could be inheriting from -- generally speaking, the Java compiler does not generate any code for you. Are you using any other framework? If so, please create an [mcve] because with vanilla Java, *this code does **not** compile*.